# I am getting Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Issue on angular js application on routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create one angular application and I am getting following error:

angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20…ttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2FHotelAdmin%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

Example code:

```
   <header class="main-header" ng-include="'template/header.html'"></header>
   <aside class="main-sidebar" ng-include="'template/nav.html'"></aside>
   <div class="content-wrapper" ui-view></div>
   <footer class="main-footer" ng-include="'template/footer.html'" ></footer>
   <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark" ng-include="'template/rightsidebar.html'"></aside>

</div><!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- REQUIRED JS SCRIPTS -->

<!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

app.js

angular
    .module('app', [
        'ui.router'
        ])
        .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function  ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
           $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

```
       $stateProvider
         .state('home',{
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'pages/dashboard.html'
        })

    }])
```

Why this error is coming any clue?
When I clicked on the link I am getting following details:
Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using ui-router, not angular-route, so you must include a script tag for ui-router:

```
<script src="...angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
angular .module('app', [ 'ui.router' ]) .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
var injector = angular.injector(["ng","http"]);
    injector.invoke();
.....});
```

I am not sure of the answer